# Passing Gitlab variable from one stage to another stage rules

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am trying to pass variable values from one stage to another stage and using it with "rules". code snippet is given below.

```yaml
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Build start"
    - VAR1=yes >> variables.env
    - echo $VAR1
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env
trigger-pipeline:
  stage: child
#  when: manual
  trigger:
    include: child/.gitlab-ci.yaml
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
  rules: 
    - if: $VAR1 == "yes"
```

Expected output: child pipeline will be triggered. But am getting below error.

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: trigger-pipeline job: undefined need: build Learn more

Comment: Your YAML indentation is a bit messed up, it matters a lot in these cases. Can you check it matches your current config?

Comment: Doens't the `need:` simply need to read `build-job` in this case?

Comment: Are you saying without the use of artificats?

Comment: No, check the name you Dave set in the needs statement. It looks like it needs the stage `build`, not the job `build-job`.

Comment: I set this and pipeline passed:
needs:
    - job: build-job
but the child pipeline didn't trigger

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules):

> You cannot use dotenv variables created in job scripts in rules, because rules are evaluated before any jobs run.